# The item you tried to buy is no longer available?

Tags: ios, ipad, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have implemented In-App-Purchase on iPad and updated application with new code.

It's approved by apple but some of mine customer not able to download our application after that I have tried to purchase application on my own iPad but I have got same error why?.

I think it's an problem with updates but I am not able to figure it out please, give me some idea how I can avoid this?

I think this problems comes to customer who have already applications on there devices but they are not able to update there application with new update and getting error.

Comment: Do you have any logfiles, etc... ?

Comment: please explain further. or post some code of how u r requesting the products.

Comment: How I can see logfiles when I am downloading application from appstore?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you provide some kind of log files, just check through your code to make sure that the product IDs are correct and that your entitlements file works. If you build the app for development, does the in-app purchase work?

Comment: Application is approved by apple and it is on appstore. Product ID is correct. There is no entitlements file. Yes during development it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's an Apple thing.  Had the same problem after an update was approved.  Didn't contact Apple, just gave it a couple of hours and it came good.